# How to Sum Groups and provide totals in separate columns?

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sum

I have beek looking at this problem for a while and while i know i could do this programiticly in LINQ. I started thinking about solutions that would scale if this were a vary large data set. I'm building my experieance with SQL and believe there is a way to get the result with out performing an insert.

What I have is data that looks like this:

```
ids type    total
A01 x   1
A01 x   2
A01 x   3
A01 y   4
B01 y   2
B01 x   3
B01 y   1
C01 x   1
C01 y   2
C01 x   5
C01 y   6
```

What I want is data that looks like this:

```
id  x total y total
A01 6   4
B01 3   3
C01 6   8
```

I's my belief incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ...
  SUM(CASE type WHEN'x' THEN total ELSE 0 END),
  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'y' THEN total ELSE 0 END)
   ...
  Group by
      Id
```

Sorry hard to give full answer on phone

Comment: I think you want to sum a count.  That's the right format, but "total" won't work.

Comment: @mark sqldev: conditional sum is what is needed. Why sum of count?

Comment: I see, you've got it then, the data looked to me like an ID.  You're right (+1)

Answer (score 1):

This is called a pivot table, and there are a number of ways to accomplish it.

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or later, the `PIVOT` operator ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)) is a neat option:

```
select id, [x], [y]
from temp d
  PIVOT ( sum(total) for type in ([x],[y]) ) p
```